# Using sumproduct to calculate values according to year

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have an interesting problem I cant figure out! I have a file which might make it easier but I will try to explain.

I have 4 worksheets in one workbook. Datasheet, Homeloans, YR2, Table.

On Datasheet in M2 I have a Date formatted as d-mmm-yy

On Homeloans I have Dates from A1:L1 which are derived from the date on Datasheet =DATE(YEAR(Datasheet!$M$2),MONTH(Datasheet!$M$2)+0,1) that progress up to =DATE(YEAR(Datasheet!$M$2),MONTH(Datasheet!$M$2)+11,1) in L1 In A2:L2 I have values entered

On YR2 I have the same setup. The date system is setup to look like a fiscal year instead of a calendar year.

On the Table sheet from B1:Y1 I have dates. B1 uses the formula =IF(Datasheet!M2<>"",TEXT(Datasheet!M2,"d-mmm-yy"),"Jan") B2 uses =IF(OR(B$1="",B$1=""),"",TEXT(EDATE(B$1,1),"d-mmm-yy")) and is propagated to Y1.

In B2:Y2 I am using this formula =SUMPRODUCT(--(TEXT(Homeloans!$A$1:$L$1,"d-mmm-yy")=B$1),Homeloans!$A$2:$L$2) with it changing respectively to Y2

This is the tricky part.

On Table, Cell C18 I have a data validation list setup to select a year number

On Table, E18 I have formula =SUMPRODUCT(--(RIGHT(TEXT($B$1:$Y$1,"d-mmm-yy"),1)+0=$C$18),$B$2:$Y$2)

Here is the problem.

If I set the date on Datasheet to 1/11/2011 and I select year one on C18 on the Table sheet, I get the correct sum on E18.

If I change the date on Datasheet to 1/11/2012 it flips the value in E18 to zero. This is the weird part. If I change the value in C18 to 2 for second year, then it gives me the correct sum. So I played with the formula =SUMPRODUCT(--(RIGHT(TEXT($B$1:$Y$1,"d-mmm-yy"),1)+0=$C$18),$B$2:$Y$2) and found that if I change the highlighted part to +-1 then select year one again, it gives me the correct sum.

It sort of does what I need it to do but the problem is for every date set I will have to go in and change that value up and down the number line according to the date on Datasheet and that just isnt going to work. It need to be dynamic and pull values based on the year the values show up in.

So if a payment is entered for example on 1/11/11 as the first payment and the second payment on 1/12/11, and I want to know the totals for the first year of the loan, it should only give me that value in E18.

Any help in resolving this would be greatly appreciated. Im running out of forehead to bang against the wall!

Regards, D

Comment: That's a lot of text. What happens when you run the formula through the Evaluate Formula tool? Where do things "go wrong"? That is where you need to apply your focus.

Comment: Yeah I know.  That is why I think it would be easier to get help if someone would be willing to look at the file.   It doesnt give an error.  It works perfectly so long as I use specific years as the start year of loans.

Comment: "It would be easier to get help if someone would be willing to look at the file. " - that sounds like you expect us to do your job, which is out of scope here.  Please evaluate your formula as Teylyn has suggested,  also rework your question,  explain what's exactly wrong and remove what's not relevant.

Comment: Anyone else have anything of value to add?

Answer (score 0):

You talk about "year one" and "second year" but your formula isn't summing for "year one" or "year two" but only for years **ending** in 1 or 2, which might not be the same thing.

If "year one" is always the same year as the date in `B1` perhaps try this formula in `E18`

`=SUMPRODUCT(--(RIGHT($B$1:$Y$1,2)=$C$18-1+RIGHT($B$1,2)),$B$2:$Y$2)`

Comment: Hi Barry, I appreciate your help.  I understand what you mean.  I tried what you came up with, it didnt return a result.  The Date in B1 is not ever static, as the date on datasheet can change thereby changing the date sequence on the table sheet.  Maybe what I am trying to accomplish isnt possible with excel.  I dont know?